# radical of the Jacobian ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, partial-derivative, ideals

Let $R=\mathbf{k}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$.

**Definition**: For $f\in R$, let $\mathcal{J}_f$ denotes the ideal generated by the partial derivatives of $f$ (Jacobian ideal), namely 
$$\mathcal{J}_f = \left\langle\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_n} \right\rangle$$

**Question**: Does there exist $f\in R$ such that $f^m\in \mathcal{J}_f$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$, but $f\not\in\mathcal{J}_f$?

In other words is it possible that $\mathcal{J}_f\subsetneq \sqrt{\mathcal{J}_f}$?

Comment: Two remarks: 1) since you already have an $f$, you'd want to say: "Does there exist $g\in R$ such that...", 2) Any ideal $I$ is a subset of its radical, so you're actually asking: "Is it possible that $\mathcal{J}_f\neq \sqrt{\mathcal{J}_f}$".

Comment: The $f$ used in the definition is just for the purpose of the definition of $\mathcal{J}_f$. So changing $f$ to $g$ will not change anything, expcept possibly the less confusing! Regarding the subset observation, yes, I want the unequality of the two ideals.

Comment: Well, that's the point, to be as clear as possible. You should edit your question... Anyway, here's your answer. Yes, it's possible. Let $f=X_1^{n+1}$ with $n>1$, then $\mathcal{J}_f=(X_1^n)$, meaning $\sqrt{\mathcal{J_f}}=(X_1)\neq (X_1^n)$; i.e. $X_1^n\in \mathcal{J}_f$ but $X_1\notin \mathcal{J_f}$.

Comment: But when exactly do we have $J_f=\sqrt {J_f}?$